# Angular: how to override a component template without writing a new component

Tags: angular, angular-aot

I'm looking for a way to use my components replacing the standard templates with custom ones, but still keeping AOT compatibility.

I know it can be done writing a new component which replaces the original template, but I'd like to provide some convention-over-configuration instead.

**Goal**: if you use *my-component* and want to replace its original template, you just have to create a template named `overrides/my-component.html` in the folder hosting the parent component.

Take for instance the *ad-banner* component used in the [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) official Angular example: in that example *hero-job-ad* and *hero-profile* components are simply meant at replacing the original template within a certain context.
I consider that code as quasi-configuration, so I'd like to provide some convention over it.

I thought this feature could be implemented adding some custom resource loader to webpack at compile time, but so far I cannot figure out how.

Comment: the closest you can really get is by good use of the ng-template directive. It would not achieve exactly what you're looking for but I've seen good results with it. It provides a way of having more flexible / dynamic templates within a component. If what you're actually looking for is reuse of functionality across components, consider a directive instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in solution - but since you want to have compile time override posibility, why than how about writing shell script that will recursively copy everything from overrides to corresponding directories in main sources.

Another option would be to use dynami components 
https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e

Comment: Automating the copy of overrides over the original templates wouldn't support multiple overrides for the same component (at different contexts)